# How could I reponse if my American friend joked "americans are foolish; we have no idea about geography?"

Tags: jokes, humor

Last time my American friend and I were talking about an African country. He happened to know nothing about the country. Then he joked "Americans are foolish; we have no idea about geography?"

I really did not see how to response in a polite, cool and nice way. So I just responded "come on". Any better way to respond? Thanks.

Comment: Just say in a joking manner, "Yeah, apparently you're all a bunch of idiots."

Comment: Also, we would ask **How could I respond..** not 'What could I response...'?

Comment: Give him Bismarck's response: *God has a special providence for fools, drunkards, and the United States of America.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If you say so* is a nice way to respond, and allows you to acknowledge what your friend says without agreeing or disagreeing with it.

*You can say that again* is a way to agree with what he has stated, and reinforce his own statement.

*You're damn right* is an emphatic way to state agreement with his assertion.